# How do I join the word "Sheet" and an integer to form sheet code name

Tags: excel, vba

How can I concatenate the word "Sheet" with a number (say, 2) to form a string that can be used as the code name of a sheet.
I've tried the following piece of code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Sh = "Sheet" & 2
Range("A1") = Sh.index
```

Comment: You have to cast the integer as a string. “Sheet” & Str(2) should do the trick, or if you are using an integer variable myInt = 2: “Sheet” & Str(myInt)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  `Codename` is assigned when the worksheet is created.  It can be changed in the properties window. In order to change it programmatically, you need to enable `Trust Access to the VBA object model`. Otherwise, it's a read-only property.  The `Index` pdroperty has to do with the order that the worksheets appear in the workbook (and will change if you move the worksheets around).

Comment: Sheets(1).Range("A1") = "Sheet(" & 2 & ")"

Comment: @BrightJovanny Posted an answer to your question assuming that you want to check if a given ►string argument refers to a valid `Code(Name)` in the VBA project. Take also note of the valid comment of @RonRosenfeld.

Comment: @Ethan I've tried that but it didn't work,  although, the code was  executed without any issue but did not produce the result.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld No, I'm not trying to change the codename of a sheet. I'm only trying to write a function that accesses the property of a sheet given the number in the codename.

Comment: As you apparently discovered (in a comment of yours), you'll need to loop through the sheets to find a match, in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer the sheet just based on index you could try something like this as well ... hope it works for you

```
Sub trial()
i = 2
Sheets(i).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I *assume* you want to check if a given ►string argument (`CodeNameString`) refers to a valid **Code(Name)** in the VBA project. *)

If so, the following function returns the worksheet to be set to memory; otherwise the second argument `IsAvailable` passed *by reference* will change to `False` and can be used for error checks (c.f. `ExampleCall` below).

```
Function SheetByCodename(ByVal CodeNameString As String, ByRef IsAvailable As Boolean) As Object
    'check for same CodeName in Sheets collection
    Dim ws As Object
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.CodeName = CodeNameString Then   ' check for string identity
            Set SheetByCodename = ws           ' set sheet object to memory
            IsAvailable = True                 ' assign true to 2nd argument passed ByRef
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
Sub ExampleCall()
dim cnt  As Long: cnt = 2        ' << change example counter 
Dim okay As Boolean              ' << needed variable passed as 2nd function argument
With SheetByCodename("Sheet" & cnt, okay)
    If okay Then
        Debug.Print _
        "a) Worksheet Name: " & .Name & vbNewLine & _
        "b) Sheet's Code(Name) in Project: " & .CodeName
    Else
        Debug.Print "Given string refers to no valid Code(Name)."
        'do other stuff to handle the wrong input
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

*) Take note of @RonRosenfeld 's important remarks in comment:

> "Codename is assigned when the worksheet is created. It can be changed in the properties window. In order to change it programmatically, you need to enable Trust Access to the VBA object model. Otherwise, it's a read-only property. "

Comment: I'm neither trying to check if a given string refers to a valid codename nor attempting to change the codename of a sheet. I'm only trying to write a function that accesses the property of a sheet given the number in the codename. I ended up looping through all the sheets.  `for i = 1 to Sheets.Count` to see if `Sheets(i).CodeName = "Sheet" & Num`

Comment: @BrightJovanny - you commented: *"I'm only trying to write a function that accesses the property of a sheet given the number in the codename"* - that's exactly what I did in above code to set/access a sheet by its numeric part in the codename - try again and feel free to accept / upvote if helpful :-) But maybe you might be sort of confusing the sheet's Excel name (e.g. "Sheet2") with the Code(Name) property hardcoded as `Sheet2`.